# My Mac keeps forgetting settings

Tags: mac, settings

My Mac seems to keep forgetting the following settings:

- I have to type my wireless password everyday (and checking "remember").
- I couldn't permanently set a particular app to be the default opener of a .php file.
- When I wake my Mac up from sleep, I need to reconnect the mouse before it can be used.

Why could this be?

Comment: We need some more information such as: Which version of OS X are you running? What type of Mac is this? iMac, Macbook, etc?

Comment: Did you repair permissions already (via Disk Utility)?

Comment: How is the mouse thing relevant? Does it stop talking to the mouse so you have to disconnect and reconnect the mouse so it works?

Comment: i have got macbook pro, mac osx 10.7.4.
i didn't try repair permission

Comment: @CajunLuke when mac waked up from sleep (or morning times), didn't auto connect to mouse.

Comment: @levye Does it happen with a different user?

Comment: Would you happen to have Filevault 1 enabled? If OS X with Filevault 1 enabled isn't properly shut down, it may happen that some things are not written to disk. I've had my preferences vanishing several times when using 10.6.x with Filevault 1.

Comment: Try repairing user permissions. This is different from the permissions repair found in Disk Utility and requires you to boot into Recovery Mode. Details can be found at this article on my blog: http://mnch.us/bEcra